# Use field values to populate another checkbox on submit.

Tags: javascript

How would I go about writing a javascipt that On Submit, would check if two fields are blank, and if they are NOT blank, then it would automatically set another field to "TRUE"? Example:

Invoice Table--
CustomerID,
InvoiceID,
Check,
Cash#,
Paid

I want the function to check if there are any values in Cash or Check# then check the Paid checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=submit onclick='var a=document.getElementById("cash"); if(a && a.value != ""){document.getElementById("paid").selected = true;}; return true;'>
```

Might need a little syntax checking on this one.